# How to read UDID, Major, Minor of beacon on android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am trying to develop a BLE application for Android.

Is the any way through which i can detect and read UDID, Major, Minor of beacon on android devices?

I have read the RadiusNetworks android-ibeacon-service, but I can't understand why:

```
major = (256 * (0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[(i + 20)]) +
 (0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[(i + 21)]));
```

which `paramArrayOfByte` is `LeScanCallback byte[] scanRecord`

Answer (score 5):

When you get the `byte[] scanRecord` from `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback`, it will include the Bluetooth LE headers, which can be variable length depending on the type of iBeacon.

Because of the variable length headers the four bytes that indicate an iBeacon advertisement (`4c 00 02 15`) may begin anywhere from the third byte (`scanRecord[2]`) up to the sixth byte (`scanRecord[5]`).  In [the latest code](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/blob/master/src/main/java/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/IBeacon.java), the [Android iBeacon Library](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service) finds the index position of the `4c 00 02 15` within the `scanRecord` and calls it the `startByte`.  Everything else is at a fixed position relative to that `startByte`.

Answer (score 5):

1. `scanRecord` should be parsed as a list of *AD structures*.
2. **iBeacon is a kind of AD structures**.

With [nv-bluetooth](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-bluetooth), you can extract iBeacon like the following.

```java
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
{
    // Parse the payload of the advertising packet.
    List<ADStructure> structures =
        ADPayloadParser.getInstance().parse(scanRecord);

    // For each AD structure contained in the advertising packet.
    for (ADStructure structure : structures)
    {
        if (structure instanceof IBeacon)
        {
            // iBeacon was found.
            IBeacon iBeacon = (IBeacon)structure;

            // Proximity UUID, major number, minor number and power.
            UUID uuid = iBeacon.getUUID();
            int major = iBeacon.getMajor();
            int minor = iBeacon.getMinor();
            int power = iBeacon.getPower();

            ........
```

See "[iBeacon as a kind of AD structures](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/03/ibeacon-as-kind-of-ad-structures.html)" for details.