# Android Bluetooth Low Energy - iBeacon

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

Recently I got a iBeacon device with the intention of creating Android Apps than can recognize it and use it. I'm new using bluetooth in Android Apps and there many things than I still don't know. Looking in the Internet and in this forum I found recommendations to use the Radius Networks' Android IBeacon Library but, alas, now it's no longer available:

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service

So I started by using the code shown in Android Developers' guide about Bluetooth Low Energy:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Using this code I can detect the device, even connect to it, but I don't know how to get the Proximity Uuid and the Major and Minor values: the app shows a lot of Uuids from services and characteristics of the device, but none is the Proximity Uuid of the device.

Anyone could tell me how to get that data using the Android Bluetooth LE API, or help me to get the Radius Networks' Android iBeacon library for Eclipse and a guide to use it or sample showing how to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Well at least you can get back to the last commit and browse the files there: https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/tree/800a1d1b24e1d5f13f4589412ce5c6bf3f7bc3f1

Comment: i have sam problem when i was comparing uuid of which is i am sending from ios application and i am receiving device uuid but but its different id and one more thing is i m not able to get major id and minor id. i am refering [this](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag) example

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT/UPDATE:***
**It gets better.. [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org/) !**
Check the [AltBeacon specifications](https://github.com/AltBeacon/spec)

> AltBeacon brings greater transparency to what a beacon transmits and
>   how that data can be used by Android, Windows and other devices.

---

*Why the Android iBeacon Library by RadiusNetworks is no longer available:*

> Vendors have started complying with guidelines set by Apple and have,
>   as a result, been forced to ‘scrub’ their products of any references
>   or connection between Android devices and their detection of iBeacon
>   protocols.

Read more:
[Apple cracks down on iBeacon for Android](http://beekn.net/2014/07/ibeacon-for-android/)
  I think the best bet seems to be from somebody who has been using it, already has it, can share it with you, as from previous commits, you may not get every component - library, sample, service

Also: [A note from the CEO for Android iBeacon Lib, RadiusNetworks](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/07/14/a-note-from-the-ceo.html)

Now, coming to *Proximity UUID* and *major*, *minors*:
I have not found a direct way to get it, in terms of a parameter, though you can have a look at [read major, minor, uuid of beacons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782532/how-to-read-udid-major-minor-of-beacon-on-android-devices)  and [SensorTag using iBeacon Technology](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/File:SensorTag_Beacon_usecase.png). In the latter, there is an indication of major, minor, uuid after iBeacon Service, however TI instruments might be the restriction.

In android, as an identifier.. you can recover the `device address`by `device.getAddress()` of the beacon/for each `BluetoothDevice device;`.

Comment: The device address is not particularly useful for iBeacon type applications, rather the data you want is in the scan record delivered to onLeScan()

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are right..that is why i am saying you can use it as an identifier..coupled with rssi, we can use it in terms of the  proximity related functionality, and from the rest of the data returned in the byte[] with the onLeScan(), apparently,its not deduced without the extra processing

Comment: You really don't want to use the BLE device address - for one thing, it's invisible on iOS, so you'll be stuck with an Android-only system.  If the goal is to build something interoperable with the "iBeacon" packet format, then you need to *quite trivially* parse the region UUID, major, and minor out of the data buffer provided to your onLeScan() callback.

Comment: how do you do that "quite trivially" ? and by the way, Apple is operating in a way which leads to disengaging the interoperability.  
Also, there is nothing mentioned in the question to indicate that 
being "invisible to iOS" would be a problem. The hardware device(for BLE) is independent of Android or iOS, plus iOS can always work the normal iBeacon way

Comment: Bluntly, if you are using the BLE device address, you are not decoding "iBeacon" as mentioned in the question but rather making your own unique scheme.  As for decoding it, have you even bothered to look at the buffer contents onLeScan() provides for a known beacon yet?

Comment: please answer the question, instead of providing a question as an answer

Comment: Someone who wants to accomplish the goal should look at the data for themselves, and in doing so will readily see how it can be done.

Comment: still haven't answered "how do you do that 'quite trivially'?" , would just help the cause

Comment: @ChrisStratton do have a look at the edit, now we'l be able to "do that trivially" : p )

Comment: Actually, no.  You are in the same place you were before, in that you'll still need to examine the data yourself to identify the fields of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The following two are totally different things, although both are called UUID.

- UUIDs of GATT services which are hosted on a BLE peripheral device.
- Proximity UUID of iBeacon.

What you should know about "UUIDs of GATT services":

1. BLE peripheral devices may implement a GATT server.
2. A GATT server hosts GATT services.
3. What the API "android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.getServices()" returns is a list of GATT services (List<BluetoothGattService>).
4. BluetoothGattService.getUuid() returns the ID of the service.

What you should know about "Proximity UUID of iBeacon":

1. BLE peripheral devices broadcast advertising packets.
2. The payload part of an advertising packet contains a list of AD structures.
3. An AD structure consists of (1) Length (1 byte), (2) AD Type (1 byte) and (3) AD Data. The AD structure format is described in "11 ADVERTISING AND SCAN RESPONSE DATA FORMAT" of "Bluetooth Core Specification 4.2".
4. iBeacon is a kind of AD structures.
5. AD Type of iBeacon is 0xFF (which means Manufacturer Specific Data).
6. The first 4 bytes of AD Data of iBeacon are 0x4C, 0x00, 0x02 and 0x15. The first 2 bytes (0x4C, 0x00) mean "Apple, Inc." and the next 2 bytes (0x02, 0x15) mean "iBeacon format".
7. Proximity UUID (16 bytes), major number (2 bytes in big endian), minor number (2 bytes in big endian), and power (1 byte) follow the first 4 bytes.

So, what you have to do to get iBeacon information (Proximity UUID, major, minor, power) are as follows.

1. Parse a payload of an advertising packets as a list of AD structures.
2. For each AD structure, check if AD Type is 0xFF and the first 4 bytes of AD Data are 0x4C, 0x00, 0x02 and 0x15.
3. When the conditions of 2. are satisfied, parse the remaining bytes as Proximity UUID, major number, minor number, and power.

If you use [nv-bluetooth](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-bluetooth), you can extract iBeacon from an advertising packet like the following:

```java
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
{
    // Parse the payload of the advertising packet.
    List<ADStructure> structures =
        ADPayloadParser.getInstance().parse(scanRecord);

    // For each AD structure contained in the advertising packet.
    for (ADStructure structure : structures)
    {
        if (structure instanceof IBeacon)
        {
            // iBeacon was found.
            IBeacon iBeacon = (IBeacon)structure;

            // Proximity UUID, major number, minor number and power.
            UUID uuid = iBeacon.getUUID();
            int major = iBeacon.getMajor();
            int minor = iBeacon.getMinor();
            int power = iBeacon.getPower();

            ........
```

See "[iBeacon as a kind of AD structures](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/03/ibeacon-as-kind-of-ad-structures.html)" for details.

Answer (score 1):

RadiusNetworks has "re-released" the libraries and examples in conjunction with a new cross platform beacon proximity spec.

[New AltBeacon Standard Allows Cross-Platform Proximity Apps](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/07/28/new-altbeacon-standard.html)

Check out [altbeacon.org](http://altbeacon.org).